# MyString.ToLower() OR MyString.ToLowerCase()

Tags: c#, .net, string

Are the following instructions similar? Do they produce the same effect?

```
MyString.ToLower()
MyString.ToLowerCase()
```

Comment: Well, the best would be to use the existing one ;)

Comment: is `ToLowerCase()` even a method? I'm not seeing it in the API

Comment: If you're seeing a `ToLowerCase()` method on the string type, it may be an extension method.  A fairly useless extension method at that.

Answer (score 10):

C# has no `String.ToLowerCase()` method so your only option is `String.ToLower` or `String.ToLowerInvariant` (which uses Invariant Culture to produce the lower case version).

The only exception would be if somebody wrote their own `ToLowerCase()` extension method. In that case, it's impossible for us to know if the behavior is the same since it's a custom implementation.

Comment: Could be an [extension method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method#Current_C.23_solutions)...

Comment: @UweKeim there may also be a `ToLowestCaseYouCan` extension method. But it's hard to answer on a method which is not in the framework (or a named lib).

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not the same.

`myString.ToLower()` will return a new string with the content of `myString` converted to lower case.

`myString.ToLowerCase()` will result in a compile-time error because `System.String` does not have a method called `ToLowerCase`.

Of course, there could be an extension method called `ToLowerCase` somewhere in your project, in which case the answer depends on the implementation of that method.

Comment: In addition, it _could_ be an extension method.

Comment: Has anyone mentioned extension methods yet?    :)